# flutter - how to access map string entries key

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-getx

i am using getx localization. And my app has a list view inside Text widget.

I try to write in Text widget every language 'name_1' value. But i can not access them.

My translation map below:

```
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
    'tr_TR': {
      'name_1': 'Dünya',
      'short_desc_1': 'Dünyadan',
          
    },
    'en_US': {
      'name_1': 'world',
      'short_desc_1': 'from world'
      },
    'de_DE': {
      'name_1': 'world',
      'short_desc_1': 'from world'
      },
    'fr_FR': {
      'name_1': 'world',
      'short_desc_1': 'from world'}
      };
```

I get value below

```
TranslateStrings().keys[locale]!['name_' + '2']!.tr
```

But i need to get this with index value.

```
TranslateStrings().keys[locale]!['name_' + index.tostring()]!.tr
```

If i write index instead of '2' i am getting error.

> _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

**SOLVED**

```
TranslateStrings().keys[locale]!['name_' + '${index + 1}']!.tr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here some magic trick for you

```
  keys.forEach(
    (k, v) {
      print(k); //k for keys like  'tr_TR'
      print(v); //v for the map after the key then access the inner value with v['name_1']
    },
  );
```

Comment: but all of your name is 'name_1' why do you want to replace 1 with index?

Comment: Because i have a list and it index 120 so, my translations has name_1 .... name_120

Comment: try this ['name_' + '${index + 1}']

Comment: Ohh man, really  thanks so much. I forgot that index start with 1 in translations. many thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251109/discussion-between-ccp-and-jancooth).